# Quisque vel risus felis

Tags: lorem-ipsum

Donec sed elementum tellus. Nulla condimentum maximus elit sit amet tristique. Aliquam ultrices nibh in urna sagittis consectetur. Cras aliquam consectetur molestie?

```
<marquee direction="up">A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors aren't showing up due to the fact the input tags are wrapped within list item tags.

To ensure the error messages show they must be the next element in the DOM after the input field. Like this:

```
<form class="contact" action="booking.php" method="POST" data-abide>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
   <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required />
   <small class="error">Please provide your full name</small>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
   <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="E-mail" required pattern="email" />
   <small class="error">Please provide a valid email address</small>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
   <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
   <small class="error">Please enter a message</small>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button right" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.